# Code Lens option not available

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Why would the new `Code Lens` option not be available in Visual Studio 2013 Professional? How can I add it (back?) into VS2013?

Example on how it should look:
[image]

Example on how my Options looks:
[image]

Comment: FYI Code Lens is available in VS2015 Professional.  Good on you Microsoft!

Comment: Looks like CodeLens is now part of VS Professional 2015 (http://aka.ms/vs2015compare).

Comment: Yeh i was disappointed to see that today in 2013. I hoped ReSharper would have an equivalent but it doesnt!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Code Lens is not included in the VS 2013 Pro SKU. You need to have the Ultimate SKU to get this feature. Others have already asked for this...

[Hey, Microsoft: Make CodeLens Available in Visual Studio 2013 Professional](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/onward-and-upward/2013/10/move-codelens-downstream.aspx)

So technically the answer to "how" is pay Microsoft a *lot* of money and upgrade to Ultimate. This isn't the answer you are looking for but for now it is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft released the product comparison details for the different versions of Visual Studio 2015 and Code Lens has been added to the Professional SKU.

[VS 2015 Compare Editions](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs)

A request was made on the Visual Studio UserVoice site to add CodeLens to other SKU's than Ultimate and MS had originally declined it.

[Make CodeLens available outside Ultimate](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4150271-make-codelens-available-outside-of-ultimate)

As you can read by the comments, in the UserVoice request many people are very unhappy by Microsoft's decision.  It looks like this original decision has been reversed.  I would assume they will updated the UserVoice very soon.